# Save Byte Array to UNC Path

Tags: c#

When I use

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("\\server\\tmp\\" + FileName, fileData);
```

It always seems to add "C:" to the beginning so it tries to save to c:\server\temp...

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Try a string-literal (prepending the `@`): `WriteAllBytes(@"\\server\tmp\" + FileName, fileData);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this is because the double backslash isn't escaped.

Try this instead:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"\\server\tmp\" + FileName, fileData);
```

Answer (score 5):

Your current path evaluates to `\server\tmp\...` which will default to `c:\server\tmp\...`.

To make a UNC path, you'll need an extra escaped directory-separator:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("\\\\server\\tmp\\" + FileName, fileData);
```

*or* you can use a string-literal instead:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"\\server\tmp\" + FileName, fileData);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about his:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(@"\\server\tmp", FileName), fileData);
```